# Jquery failed to change Div border colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement "changing Div border color" when clicking on one of the radio buttons. It works well for scenario 1 but won't work on scenario 2.

[image]

```js
$(":radio:checked").closest(".discount").addClass("checked");
$(":radio").on("change", e => {
  const $div = $(e.target).closest(".discount");
  console.log($div);
  $(".discount").removeClass("checked");
  $div.addClass("checked");
});

$(":radio:checked").closest(".discount2").addClass("checked");
$(":radio").on("change", e => {
  const $div = $(e.target).closest(".discount2");
  console.log($div);
  $(".discount2").removeClass("checked");
  $div.addClass("checked");
});
```

```css
.discount {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.discount.checked {
  border-color: red;
}
.discount2 {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.discount2.checked {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label style="width:100%">
  <div class="discount">
    <input type="radio" name="fruits" checked>Apple</div>
</label>
<label style="width:100%">
  <div class="discount">
    <input type="radio" name="fruits">Banana</div>
</label>

<label style="width:100%">
  <div class="discount2">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks" checked>Milk</div>
</label>
<label style="width:100%">
  <div class="discount2">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks">Zzz</div>
</label>
<label style="width:100%">
  <div class="discount2">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks">Bbb</div>
</label>
```

In scenario 2, when clicking on 'Zzz', the Div border "Red" is gone! Anyone know whats wrong ?

Comment: Make a fiddle bro

Comment: @Eric bro, I try to put that on Fiddle. But when adding "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"  it cause some error.

Comment: $(".discount").removeClass("checked"); - this line is always executed, right? And that's problem. You will have to make less greedy selectors...and to cover all possible scenarios with one code block.

Comment: @gosulove you don't need to add libs. Hits the "options wheel" (top right) and choose from external libs

Comment: @gosulove you just deleted your javascript when you added the fiddle...

Comment: @nevermind yes.. but i not sure how to fix this issue... If i remove that line.  the whole thing won't work as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use multiple clases and such:

(I added another version of the example, where no `<div>`s were used (and changed the coloring a bit)

```js
$('input[type=radio]:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
$('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(e) {
  var thisGroup = $(this).attr('name');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[name='+thisGroup+']').parent().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    }
 });
```

```css
.discount, .discount-label{
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    padding:2px;
    padding:10px;
    width:10%;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.discount.checked,.discount-label.checked {
    border-color: red;
}
.discount-label input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
  }
.discount-label.checked {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><div class="discount"><input type="radio" name="fruits" checked>Apple</div></label>
<label><div class="discount"><input type="radio" name="fruits">Banana</div></label>

<label><div class="discount"><input type="radio" name="drinks" checked>Milk</div></label>
<label><div class="discount"><input type="radio" name="drinks">Zzz</div></label>
<label><div class="discount"><input type="radio" name="drinks">Bbb</div></label>

<h2>example two</h2>
<label class="discount-label"><input type="radio" name="fruits2" checked>Apple</label>
<label class="discount-label"><input type="radio" name="fruits2">Banana</label>

<label class="discount-label"><input type="radio" name="drinks2" checked>Milk</label>
<label class="discount-label"><input type="radio" name="drinks2">Zzz</label>
<label class="discount-label"><input type="radio" name="drinks2">Bbb</label>
```

Comment: It's strictly not needed to use the `<div>`s at all, you could just use the `<label>` as the container.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `$(":radio").on("change")` are triggered and both the .checked classes are removed but it's only added the current changed checkbox. You can use 1 css class instead or change the javascript to remove all checked classes and add them back like you do on a page load.

```
updateBorders();

$(":radio").on("change", e => {
    const $div = $(e.target).closest(".discount");
    console.log($div);
        updateBorders();
});

function updateBorders() {
    $(".discount").removeClass("checked");
    $(".discount2").removeClass("checked");
    $(":radio:checked").closest(".discount").addClass("checked");
        $(":radio:checked").closest(".discount2").addClass("checked")
}
```

[Full JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/q3ynr94z/2/)